# Angular PWA does not work when change to OFFLINE and press Refresh (F5)

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa, service-worker-config

I'm using angular to make PWA app.

- **Angular**: 12

What is going on is:

- I go to my app (online mode) -> The web app can display properly
- Turn on developer console and change connectivity to OFFLINE
- Press F5 to reload the application

What happens:

- The below image is what it displays on the screen when I hit reload:

[image]

This is my **ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "manifest.json",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- **manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "ng-main",
  "short_name": "ng-main",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where you test this ? And using which command ?

Comment: I built my application using `ng build --configuration production` and deployed to my local IIS Server

Comment: I think you need `ng build --prod`. And if you're project having api call then you need to cache api too. And also set base path in index.html too.

Comment: I have built my project with production profile. I did as the official angular doc says, but does not work while pressing F5

Comment: Any http server call inside your project. If yes then cache it too inside datagroups. And after running project give some time to cache pwa. Any third party script call inside index.html may need to cache.

Comment: I removed the server side call, that means there is no api call in my app, the problem is still the same

Comment: One work around is create new project using angular cli. Then add pwa . and now test this default project is working or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having spent hours searching for solutions
I noticed when I built my app using `ng build --configuration production`. There is one `ngsw.json` file inside my `dist` folder.

However, the `urls` and `patterns` in the generated `ngsw.json` file are all empty, like the one below:

```
"assetGroups": [
    {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "cacheQueryOptions": {
            "ignoreVary": true
        },
        "urls": [],
        "patterns": []
    },
    {
        "name": "assets",
        "installMode": "lazy",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "cacheQueryOptions": {
            "ignoreVary": true
        },
        "urls": [],
        "patterns": []
    }
]
```

When I added the urls to cache in `assetGroups` and tried again, the application worked smoothly. (Please see the content below)

```
"assetGroups": [
    {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "cacheQueryOptions": {
            "ignoreVary": true
        },
        "urls": [
            "/login",
            "/dashboard"
        ],
        "patterns": [
            "/*.css",
            "/*.js"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "assets",
        "installMode": "lazy",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "cacheQueryOptions": {
            "ignoreVary": true
        },
        "urls": [
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/index.html",
            "/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/ngsw.json"
        ],
        "patterns": []
    }
]
```

I already reported to Angular team about this and it has been confirmed as [a bug in Angular 12](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20894).

In conclusion, now, I have to workaround by copying the `ngsw.json` file with the cached urls in `assetGroups`, after having built the application, I copy that `ngsw.json` to the `dist` folder.

Answer (score 0):

but in my case the URLs are not empty in the `ngsw.json` at `dist/myproject` but still in offline mode it not working. throwing the error

The Error is

```
 ngsw.json URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.2758348374356183
```

Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
Fetch: ngsw-worker.js:2925
Size: 0 B
Time: 3 ms